# Why does my database query code fail in PHP 7.3? But it works fine in php7.0

Tags: wordpress, php-7.3

Why does my database query code fail in PHP 7.3? But it works fine in php7.0.

This is the part of the code I'm currently using, hope to get your help

```
function is_page_activity_all_amount(){
    if( ( $cache = get_transient( 'activity_list' ) ) !== false ) return $cache;
    $value = ''; 
        global $wpdb;
    $all_amount=$wpdb->prepare("select count(*) as total from(
    select ID as nid,comment_count as cid,post_author as uid,post_title as title,post_type as ctype,post_date as time from $wpdb->posts where post_type in ('post', 'works', 'downloads', 'book' ,'topic' ,'reply') and post_status='publish'
    union all
    select comment_ID as nid, comment_post_ID as cid, user_id as uid,comment_content as title,'comment' as ctype,comment_date as time from $wpdb->comments where comment_approved = 1
    union all
    select id as nid, comment_id as cid, user_id as uid,comment_id as title,'clike' as ctype,date_time as time from ".$wpdb->prefix."ulike_comments where status='like'
  union all
    select id as nid, post_id as cid,user_id as uid,post_id as title,'plike' as ctype,date_time as time from ".$wpdb->prefix."ulike where status='like'
) as ref left join $wpdb->users as user on user.id=ref.uid where user.id!=0 and user.id<50000 order by time desc");

    $quantity = $wpdb->get_results( $all_amount );
    $value = $quantity[0]->total;
    set_transient( 'activity_list', $value, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    return $value; 
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? Are there any error messages on screen or in log files?

Comment: Completely blank without any information

Comment: If there is nothing in your error.log file on the server (not just a blank screen), try making your query really simple to see if the query is even getting run.